# How to switch style id based on var

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to switch CSS styles with jQuery - simple `if` condition. Is there any simple way to switch styles by using ID? I'm using 2 CSS blocks with different IDs.

Like this:

```
<style id="styleA">
.myDiv {
    display: none; 
}
</style>

<style id="styleB">
.myDiv {
    display: block; 
}
</style>


<div class="myDiv">Lorem</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var style = 4;

                if (style < 5)
                {
                    //use css id styleA
                } 
                else
                {
                    //use css id styleB
                }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: So you want to use a jQuery selector like this?

`$('#styleB');`

Comment: You should switch classes, not IDs.

Comment: Adding/removing classes should be preferred any day over switching style sheets.. However, you can do: http://jsfiddle.net/gbYLz/

Comment: thanks, but I'm talking about 2 blocks of css not 2 id or 2 classes

Answer (score 0):

So many errors in your code.

First off, read about the style tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style

It uses no `id` (except for the generic behaviour, just like any other element), but you can use `title` for alternate styles (read here: http://alistapart.com/article/alternate/) or use `scoped` attribute and place the style tag inside the element that needs formatting.

However, the best way would be to define additional classes in a single style tag for the same element. Like this:

```
<style>
.myDiv.hidden {
    display: none; 
}

.myDiv.shown {
    display: block; 
}
</style>
```

Then the matter of switching style is as easy as adding/removing class names to elements. Of course, instead of `hidden/shown` you can use class names that contain (but not start with) a number from your `style` variable.

Also, your if/else block makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a class to the body depending on the style value:

```
$('body').addClass('style'+style);
```

then set the css accordingly. So you can add more styles for each type easily.
 **For example:**

```
body.style4 .myDiv{
    display:none;
}
body.style5 .myDiv{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
<style type="text/css">
    .sytle1 {
        display: none; 
    }

    .style2 {
        display: block; 
    }
 </style>


    <div id="myDiv" class="">Lorem</div>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            var style = 4;

                    if (style < 5)
                    {
                        $('myDiv').addClass('style1').removeClass('style2');
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        $('myDiv').addClass('style2').removeClass('style1');
                    }
        });
    </script>
```